# Android: How to use an xml string value to determine layout orientation

Tags: android

I have a simple linear layout that I would like to change based on the screen size of the device. What I am trying to do is something like

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:orientation="@string/cover_orientation"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

I have created different dimen.xml files under values and values-xlarge so that the `cover_orientation` variable will take on a different value (either 'vertical' or 'horizontal') based on the screen size.

```
string name="cover_orientation">"vertical"
```

But this doesn't work. I have found a temporary work around that involves checking the screen size and changing the orientation manually:

```
if(getResources().getString(R.string.screen_size) == "xlarge"){
    ((LinearLayout)convertView).setOrientation(1);
}
```

but it seems like you should be able to do it the first way (much more elegant/less code).

I considered just having a different layout for each screen size, but the layout is actually quite big and this is the only change I need for the different screen sizes. So it didn't make much sense to me to duplicate the entire layout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to the problem by looking around the android docs. What I originally had was a LinearLayout, that contained an image an text inside of it (there was actually a lot more content inside of it but I'll keep it simple for this example), that looked something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

<ImageView android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/cover_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/cover_height"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/title"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:ellipsize="end" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What I wanted was to be able to dynamically change whether the text was beside the image or below the image, based on the device screen size. In other words i wanted to dynamically change the `android:orientation` dynamically. My first thought, which I posted in my question, was to have a string variable declared in the res/values/dimen.xml as

```
<string name="orientation">horizontal</string>
```

and another string variable declared in res/values-large/dimen.xml as

```
<string name="orientation">vertical</string>
```

Then when I was setting the orientation in the LinearLayout I thought I could use

```
android:orientation="@string/orientation"
```

But this didn't work. What I ended up doing was splitting the layout up. I originally had reservations about having two separate layouts because I thought I would have a lot of duplicated code for one simple change. That was before I learned about include and merge. First I created a common layout file that was the image and text in res/layout/content.xml that looked like:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  >

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/cover"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/cover_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cover_height"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/title_font_size"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:ellipsize="end" />
</merge>
```

(Sidenote: I was originally confused at what the merge tag did. It is not merging what is inside the merge tag (in this example the image and the text) it is basically saying whatever parent file includes this file, merge the contents in between the tags into the parent file)

Then I created two separate files for just the LinearLayout that included the image and description xml file. One in res/layout/container.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/library_item_container"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and one in res/layout-large/container.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:id="@+id/library_item_container"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <include layout="@layout/library_item_contents"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Notice the only difference between the two container.xml files is that the orientation has changed from vertical to horizontal. Now there is minimal code that is repeated and problem is solved!

Comment: If you used "0" instead of the string "horizontal", and "1" instead of "vertical", then your original, simple approach with @string/orientation would have worked.

Comment: @uval You should have made that into an answer instead so it would be easier to find.

Comment: @MaciejGórski Probably, but my suggestion is a hack.. (working one, but still)

Comment: @uval Actually not as much of a hack. Orientation is enum, so making it like in my answer is both readable and copypaste-less. I prefer integer, but I have checked that strings also work. Maybe boolean would too ;)

Comment: @MaciejGórski from my testing, Strings work only in the SDK builder, but not on the VM. The integer values are SDK private, that's why it feels "hackish" to me. But the strings are converted to int in compile time, so it is safe to use. I +1 your answer for turning my comment to a valid answer.

Answer (score 11):

A nice way to do this is to add

```
android:orientation="@integer/cover_orientation"
```

on your `LinearLayout` and defining it like below.

in `values/consts.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <integer name="orientation_horizontal">0</integer>
    <integer name="orientation_vertical">1</integer>

</resources>
```

in `values/something.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <integer name="cover_orientation">@integer/orientation_vertical</integer>

</resources>
```

in `values-land/something.xml`:

```
<resources>

    <integer name="cover_orientation">@integer/orientation_horizontal</integer>

</resources>
```

This way you avoid hardcoding zeros and ones in your orientation variable definitions across the app.

Comment: Great solution. However, is it documented (or future-proof)?

Comment: @AHelloWorldDev It's documented here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#orientation, so I think it is very much future proof.

Answer (score 2):

@odiggity, thank you for posting this question. I was trying the same. Application crashed upon starting.

I would assume that it's a runtime typing issue. In other words, there are only two legal values for the orientation attribute, which is not reflected by the string "type". What the framework would probably have to do is introduce another specialized resource type, similar to dimen or boolean.

I feel there is an answer to your question which addresses more cases than your own answer above. One can use **style inheritance** to define all attributes except orientation in an orientation-independent parent style and then add only the orientation in a small orientation-dependent style definition with that as a parent.

This way, one can avoid duplication even in complex cases.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do some reading: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I had read through this previous to your response but I think I`m still missing something. I have created different dimen.xml files under values, values-large and values-xlarge so that the <code>name</code> variable will take on a different value (either 'vertical' or 'horizontal') based on the screen size. 

I considered just having a different layout for each screen size, but the layout is actually quite big and this is the only change I need for the different screen sizes. So it didn't make much sense to me to duplicate the entire layout.